# Entity Framework not an ordinary complex relation

Tags: entity-framework, relation

I want to implement not an ordinary relation in Entity Framework but I still have no any good idea how to do it.

So here is the problem:

I have `EntityX` which is in many to many relation with `EntityFeature`.
`EntityZ` have a foreign key to `EntityX` but can only accept `EntityX` with `EntityFeature.Name = "A"` and `EntityX` can not break its relation with `EntityFeature with Name="A"` while it have a relation with `EntityZ`.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do it?

**Update 1:**
Any modification are acceptable while not breaking the concept

Answer (score 0):

EF is not the best way to handle this. 
You need to have a `model` where you can validate all the business rule you have.

So you simply would create a `repository` that would wrap EF update operation that can break your business rule. Repository would validate rules and apply changes if they are safe.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've solved it exactly as you suggested many months ago. From time to time I'm looking towards EF Core, but it's still have less functions than EF6.